# Execute alias in whisker search bar

Tags: xfce4-terminal, whisker-menu

I created this alias in bash:

```
alias .one='cd Learn/React/React\ JS/one_app/ && code . && exit'
```

to open a project in VSCODE, but when i try to execute in whisker search bar using `!.one` i receive the error `Failed to execute child process`. Any help?

*Linux mint 20.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The aliases you define in bash aren't available outside of bash.

If you want a command available from the whisker menu of XFCE, you need to make a `.desktop` file and in one of the locations which are standard for those files. One such location (and the one I'd recommend) is in `~/.local/share/applications`.

I suggest taking a look at other `.desktop` files to get an idea how they look, and also check out the [specification on desktop entry files](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html)

You can take a look in `/usr/share/applications` for a bunch other, system-wide `.desktop` files, too.

As an example, here's a `.desktop` file for [Gpredict](http://gpredict.oz9aec.net/):

```ini
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Gpredict
Comment=Satellite tracker
Exec=gpredict
Icon=gpredict-icon
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=HamRadio;Science;Astronomy;Education;Network;
```

You seem to want to run the application inside a specific directory, the `.desktop` definition has an entry for that: `Path=`, where you can specify the working directory to run the command in.

---

Here's an example of a `.desktop` file that does things similar what you seem to like:

```ini
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Custom VSCode
Exec=code .
Path=/home/polemon/devel/c
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Development
```

It works for me, not caring about most entries, etc.

Comment: Nice, thanks. I did it and it worked here. Helped me a lot.